# Ternary for razor html output

Tags: c#, razor

This works but it's a lot of lines:

```
if (foo == true)
{
    <td>Yes</td>
}
else
{
    <td>No</td>
}
```

This doesnt work because *Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*...

```
<td>
    @{foo == true ? "Yes" : "No";}
</td>
```

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: custom html helpers is one possible solution. Have a look at this post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52016/how-to-write-elegant-conditional-bits-of-markup-in-razor-views

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is that you picked up the wrong parenthesis, this works:

```
<td>
    @(foo == true ? "Yes" : "No")
</td>
```

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#razor-syntax):

> Explicit Razor expressions consist of an @ symbol with balanced parenthesis. To render last week's time, the following Razor markup is used:

```
<p>Last week this time: @(DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7))</p>
```